# ldap error message when compiling PHP 7.4 on Red Hat 8

Tags: php, ldap, redhat

I'm testing RH8. I'm trying to compile PHP 7.4.19 with the following configuration command. (I have dnf/yum the necessary libraries before):

```
 ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-openssl --with-zip  --with-jpeg=/usr/lib --enable-gd --enable-exif --enable-mbstring --with-ldap --with-pdo-mysql --enable-intl --enable-soap --with-mysqli
```

The configure process works fine, with no errors. This is what it shows up related to ldap:

```
checking for LDAP support... yes
checking whether to build with LDAP Cyrus SASL support... no
checking size of long... (cached) 8
checking if we're at 64-bit platform... yes
checking for 3 arg ldap_set_rebind_proc... yes
checking for ldap_parse_result... yes
checking for ldap_parse_reference... yes
checking for ldap_start_tls_s... yes
checking for ldap_control_find... yes
checking for ldap_parse_extended_result... yes
checking for ldap_extended_operation... yes
checking for ldap_extended_operation_s... yes
checking for ldap_passwd... yes
checking for ldap_whoami_s... yes
checking for ldap_refresh_s... yes
checking for ldap_bind_s... yes
```

But then, when I run "make" I got the following error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: ext/ldap/.libs/ldap.o: undefined reference to symbol 'ber_memfree'
//usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:278: sapi/cli/php] Error 1
```

Have you ever had this problem before? I haven't been able to find anything on the Internet about this error.

Any suggestion would be more than welcome. I did the same test with php 7.4.16 and I got the same error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix this issue by adding the following symbolic link:
ln -s /usr/lib64/liblber.so /usr/lib/liblber.so

I hope this solution might be useful